# Amsthm with an independent couter prepended that only increases when the theorem is called in a new subsection

Tags: counters, amsthm

So I was using `amsthm` definied as following:

```
\newtheorem{dfn}{Definition}
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{dfn}{subsection}
\makeatother
```

Which means at every subsection if I call the dfn environment the couter will start at 1, which is what I desired but I find out that it was difficult when referrencing over different (sub)sections. So what I would like to is if it it possible to prepend a counter before the original counter of dfn env, so that it behaves something like following:

---

## Section1

### Subsection 1

something called A which has

**Definition 1.1** Some definition

**Definition 1.2** And some other definition

### Subsection 2

Some other text but this subsection didn't called dfn.

### Subsection 3

**Definition 2.1** Definition for subsec 3

**Definition 2.2** And some more

---

Which I've found solution for just directly dump the subsection's numbering before the dfn counter, but that is not what I want. What I want is perhaps a independent counter that increases every time I called the environment at a different subsection. How could I achieve this?

Comment: Are you sure your readers will understand the meaning of definition 1.1 being in section 1 and 2.1 in section 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would not want to have 'Definition 2.X' in the third section because I think this is misleading.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{mycounter} \stepcounter{mycounter} % Counter mycounter has now value 1.
\newif\ifdfnused\dfnusedfalse % Define \ifdfnused an set to false. (True, when a defn-environment was used in the current section. False otherwise.)

\newtheorem{dfn}{Definition} % Define dfn-environment.
\counterwithin{dfn}{mycounter} % Reset dfn-counter whenever mycounter is incremented.
\AfterEndEnvironment{dfn}{\dfnusedtrue} % When a dfn-environment was used, set dfnused to true.

\let\oldsection\section % Save old \section-command.
\def\section{% Define new section-command:
   \ifdfnused% If dfn-environment was used ...
   \stepcounter{mycounter}% ... then increment mycounter (this will set defn-counter to 0) ...
   \fi% ... otherwise do nothing.
   \dfnusedfalse% Set dfnused to false as we start a new section (of course, in this new section there was no defn-environment until now).
   \oldsection% Start new section.
}

%%% TEST %%%

\begin{document}
   \section{Firstsection}
   \begin{dfn}
      First definition in this section.
   \end{dfn}
   \begin{dfn}
      Second definition in this section.
   \end{dfn}
   \section{Secondsection}
   This is a section without definitions.
   \section{Thirdsection}
   \begin{dfn}
      First definition in this section.
   \end{dfn}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I remember chngcntr is included with latex nowadays, so seems no need to include it anymore. Also I get your point that this numbering structure might be confusing, but to me prepending whole chapter.section.subsection numbering before a theorem seems more complicated, especially when referencing definitions within the paper.

Comment: @Andrew.Wolphoe thanks, you are right, there is no need for `chngcntr`, I will edit my answer. I agree that chapter.section.subsection.dfn would be too much, I think two or maybe three levels shold be enough. But what do you think about chapter.defn or chapter.section.defn? Then your preamble would only be `\documentclass{report} \newtheorem{dfn}{Definition} \counterwithin{dfn}{chapter}` (and maybe `\counterwithin{dfn}{section}`).

Answer (score 1):

This implements your requirements, but the numbering is *very* weird. How is one supposed to know that definition 7.1 is in subsection 3.4 or definition 3.1 in section 2?

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{predfn}
\setcounter{predfn}{1}
\newtheorem{dfn}{Definition}[predfn]

\NewCommandCopy{\latexsection}{\section}
\NewCommandCopy{\latexsubsection}{\subsection}

\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{sO{#3}m}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {% starred section, just don't worry
    \latexsection*{#3}%
   }
   {% numbered section
    \ifnum\value{dfn}>0 \stepcounter{predfn}\fi
    \latexsection[#2]{#3}%
   }%
}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\subsection}{sO{#3}m}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {% starred section, just don't worry
    \latexsubsection*{#3}%
   }
   {% numbered section
    \ifnum\value{dfn}>0 \ifnum\value{subsection}>0 \stepcounter{predfn}\fi\fi
    \latexsubsection[#2]{#3}%
   }%
}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}

\subsection{First sub}

\begin{dfn}
First definition in this section.
\end{dfn}

\begin{dfn}
Second definition in this subsection.
\end{dfn}

\subsection{Second sub}

This is a section without definitions.

\subsection{Third sub}

\begin{dfn}
First definition in this subsection.
\end{dfn}

\section{Second section}

\begin{dfn}
Definition in the second section.
\end{dfn}

\subsection{Fourth sub}

No definitions here.

\subsection{Fifth sub}

\begin{dfn}
A definition here.
\end{dfn}

\section{Third section}

\subsection{Sixth sub}

\begin{dfn}
A definition here.
\end{dfn}

\subsection{Seventh sub}

\begin{dfn}
A definition here.
\end{dfn}

\subsection{Eigth sub}

No definition here.

\subsection{Ninth sub}

\begin{dfn}
A definition here.
\end{dfn}

\end{document}
```

[image]